# Customize the More UIBarButtonItem in UITabBar

Tags: ios5, customization, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Since iOS 5 Apple provided an API to customise the `UITabBarItems` in the `UITabBar` object. I am refering specifically to the following selector:

`setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:`

It all works great for regular buttons but I can't seem to customise the "More" button to match the style of the other ones. This is what I am doing:

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = tabBarControllerArray;
    tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    UITabBarItem *more = tabBarController.moreNavigationController.tabBarItem;
     if ([more respondsToSelector:@selector(setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:)]){
        [more setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BarIcon-More.png"]
           withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BarIcon-More.png"]
         ];
    } else {
        more.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BarIcon-More.png"];
    }
```

The result is as follows, it doesn't pick-up my custom More image.

[image: Inactive more button]
[image: Ugly active more button]

I have seen many hacks to replace the more button but there's got to be a better way of doing this right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was silly.

I assumed the `UITabBarItems` in the `moreNavigationController` was readonly and it wasn't. So simply doing the following:

```
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"More" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BarIcon-More.png"] tag:0];
```

And the same customization code as above works.

Comment: This does not seem to work on iOS 6.  Setting the `tabBarItem` property on the more controller does nothing.  I can step over the assignment line in the debugger checking before and after and it doesn't change.  Any other solutions?