# Change "more" icon in a tabbar application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

When you create more than 5 tabs in a tabbar application it automatically creates a "more" tab with a custom icon of 3 dots. Is there a way to change that icon for example to an arrow or any other icon I wish to? I've tried several things including..

```
UITabBarItem *more = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4]; or
UITabBarItem *more = (UITabBarItem *)tabBarController.moreNavigationController;  or
UITabBarItem *more = (UITabBarItem *)[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];  or

[tabBarItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowSelexted.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
```

and nothing works.. I also tried allocating the tabBarItem but still nothing..

```
UITabBarItem *more = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"not" image:nil tag:0];
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.tabBarItem = more;
```

any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150788/customize-the-more-uibarbuttonitem-in-uitabbar

Comment: You need to allocate new tabbar item for the moreNavigationController and then use your customisation.

Comment: @Amar I tried UITabBarItem *more = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"not" image:nil tag:0]; tabBarController.moreNavigationController.tabBarItem = more; and it still does not work.

Answer (score 6):

You can use moreNavigationController of tabBarController:

```
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"More" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"] tag:0];
```