# Custom images and/or title for More item in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I essentially want to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150788/customize-the-more-uibarbuttonitem-in-uitabbar).  But it doesn't seem to work on iOS 6.

I have a UITabBarController that displays its More option.  I want to show custom images for that item because I have customized the tab bar.  But giving `self.moreNavigationController.tabBarItem` a new value does nothing.  Neither does assigning the existing property new images.  Is there a way to accomplish this?  It would seem pretty weird to have the ability to customize the tab bar and all the items except for the More item...

Comment: The post you're linking to... Doesn't that give you the answer?

Comment: @runmad - Nope.  Doesn't work.  It must have changed in iOS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I was doing something wrong.  It works fine.  In `viewWillAppear` I'm doing this:

```
UITabBarItem *doneItem = [[[UITabBarItem alloc]init]autorelease];
doneItem.title = @"MyMore";
[doneItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more_selected"]
          withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more"]];
self.moreNavigationController.tabBarItem = doneItem;
```